# How use COM in Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, com

I am programming in Java and I need to use the Jacob library. Jacob is a COM library and as you can see [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/jacob-project/discussion/375946/thread/5faf44b1/) I can not use it on Linux (because Jacob uses COM which is Microsoft Windows). But I know that it is possible to do programming in C# (which also is Microsoft Windows) on Linux. So maybe it is also possible to use Jacob on Linux (Ubuntu). Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What is the COM library you are going to use or are asking just using for any system library use-case? But short answer you most likely can forget Jacob and find another integration method. COM is not found in Linux, does not relate to a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

No.  This is not possible.  COM is a Microsoft Windows approach to software interoperability.  Although you can (technically) write C# on different platforms, you are in fact writing in Mono, which does not rely on the Microsoft CLR that actually allows for COM interop.